# /dev/input/event doesn't report keys being pressed

Tags: keyboard, usb-device, hid, keyboard-event, events

I have an usb keyboard connected to a linux box.

I need to capture all keys that have been  pressed and released.

[image]

My keyboard n-key rollover meaning that it doesn't have limits on number of concurrent keys being held. They are all detected and reported.

They keyboard works fine in terminal and x-windows.

I can press and hold keys one after another and each time a new character appears on the screen. I tried ten and they are all detected.

HOWEVER:

when I read data from /dev/input/eventX corresponding to keyboard the data stops coming after 6 keys has been pressed.

I wrote a small program in node.js, but I can observe the same behaviour even by doing "cat /dev/input/eventX".

It's very puzzling, because I would assume that there is a same driver that is used to read keycodes and display them in terminal.

Anyone has any idea where and why event file is not receiving any data past 6 keys?

What would be a way around this problem ?

Tried with RPI (Debian and Ubuntu), OrangePI (Ubuntu) and PC (LinuxMint).

Thanks, M

here is the node.js code

*

```
const InputEvent = require('input-event');
const input = new InputEvent('/dev/input/event0');
function keyReleased(input) {
        console.log(input.code);
}


const keyboard = new InputEvent.Keyboard(input);
keyboard.on('data'    , function(input) {
        console.log("DATA:" + input.code);
});
```

- 

Comment: From [this answer on SU](https://superuser.com/a/1558955/432690): "The USB keyboard protocol is limited to 6 keys pressed simultaneously + 3 modifier keys. To bypass this limitation, some keyboards report to the computer as a USB hub with multiple keyboards connected to it". Looks like a promising starting point for research.